# How can I subtract from subsequent column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I subtract from column before itself for many columns without hardcoding it? I can do it by hard coding it as shown below:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,2,3,4],"b":[1,3,5,6],"c":[6,7,8,9]})

df['a_diff'] = df['a']-16
df['b_diff'] = df['b']-df['a']
df['c_diff'] = df['c']-df['b']
```

I know there is a way to do it rowwise by using shift function. Can we also it as column wise? There are 100 columns I need to use this technique on so I would rather do it pythonically instead of hard coding it. Please note that "a_diff" was subtracted from constant intentionally since I will have to subtract that column by constant in my code as well.

Thank you,

Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html) and [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) (or [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) with some limitations!) then rename with [`add_suffix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_suffix.html) and [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to the original DataFrame:

```
out = df.join(df.diff(axis=1).combine_first(df[['a']].sub(16)).add_suffix('_diff'))
```

Or, if you are sure that there is no NaN in the columns other than "a":

```
out = df.join(df.diff(axis=1).fillna(df['a'].sub(16)).add_suffix('_diff'))
```

Output:

```
   a  b  c  a_diff  b_diff  c_diff
0  1  1  6   -15.0       0       5
1  2  3  7   -14.0       1       4
2  3  5  8   -13.0       2       3
3  4  6  9   -12.0       2       3
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html) with set first column by [`DataFrame.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) and [`DataFrame.add_suffix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_suffix.html), last append to original by [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df = df.join(df.diff(axis=1).fillna({'a': df['a'].sub(16)}).add_suffix('_diff'))
```

Solution without specify hardcoding first column:

```
first  = df.columns[0]
df = df.join(df.diff(axis=1).fillna({first: df[first].sub(16)}).add_suffix('_diff'))
```

Or set first column by difference:

```
df1 = df.diff(axis=1)
df1.iloc[:, 0] = df.iloc[:, 0].sub(16)
df = df.join(df1.add_suffix('_diff'))
```

Solution if not exist missing values in original DataFrame:

```
df = df.join(df.diff(axis=1).fillna(df.sub(16)).add_suffix('_diff'))
```

---

```
print (df)
   a  b  c  a_diff  b_diff  c_diff
0  1  1  6     -15       0       5
1  2  3  7     -14       1       4
2  3  5  8     -13       2       3
3  4  6  9     -12       2       3
```